# Extract data from HTML page in between Tags using HTMLUNIT

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to extract data from web page using Html Unit. I've already achieved this by converting HtmlPage to text and then extracted data by using regular expression out of that HTML page. I've also achieved to extract data from Html tables using class attribute in Html.

I want to use HtmlUnit again fully for all extraction to learn for the same requirement I have done using regular expression. Am not able to get how can I extract data within tags in the form of key value pair.

Here is the sample Html data

```
<div class="top_red_bar">
    <div id="site-breadcrumbs">
        <a href="/admin/index.jsp" title="Home">Home</a>
        &#124;
        <a href="/admin/queues.jsp" title="Queues">Queues</a>
        &#124;
        <a href="/admin/topics.jsp" title="Topics">Topics</a>
        &#124;
        <a href="/admin/subscribers.jsp" title="Subscribers">Subscribers</a>
        &#124;
        <a href="/admin/connections.jsp" title="Connections">Connections</a>
        &#124;
        <a href="/admin/network.jsp" title="Network">Network</a>
        &#124;
         <a href="/admin/scheduled.jsp" title="Scheduled">Scheduled</a>
        &#124;
        <a href="/admin/send.jsp"
           title="Send">Send</a>
    </div>
    <div id="site-quicklinks"><P>
        <a href="http://activemq.apache.org/support.html"
           title="Get help and support using Apache ActiveMQ">Support</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<table border="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="100%" style="overflow:hidden;">
            <div class="body-content">


<h2>Welcome!</h2>

<p>
Welcome to the Apache ActiveMQ Console of <b>localhost</b> (ID:TOOLCONTROLPJX526-524666-65544585445-2:3)
</p>

<p>
You can find more information about Apache ActiveMQ on the <a href="http://activemq.apache.org/">Apache ActiveMQ Site</a>
</p>

<h2>Broker</h2>


<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><b>localhost</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Version</td>
        <td><b>5.13.3</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td><b>ID:TOOLCONTROLPJX526-524666-65544585445-2:3</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Uptime</td>
        <td><b>17 days 13 hours</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Store percent used</td>
        <td><b>19</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Memory percent used</td>
        <td><b>0</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Temp percent used</td>
        <td><b>0</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to extract data in between table tag. 
Expected output

```
Name:localhost
Version:5.13.3
ID:ID:TOOLCONTROLPJX526-524666-65544585445-2:3
Uptime:7 days 13 hours
Store percent used:19
Memory percent used:0
Temp percent used:0
```

How it can be achieved? I want to know which methods to be used within HTLM unit to achieve this.

Comment: @Rcordoval, Dont think too much...Am not here for done code but the specific idea of extraction within tags using Html unit. If you see my question I've already done using other method (regex) but couldn't find or understand Htmlunit to achieve this ..!

Comment: you can find lot's of example in here https://dzone.com/articles/htmlunit-%E2%80%93-quick-introduction

Comment: HtmlUnit has many methods (in HtmlPage) to get elements (by tag name, ID, path, etc.). If the element is a table, what is returned is an HtmlTable. And HtmlTable has methods to get rows, and rows have methods to get cells. The javadoc is your friend Read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are the steps i followed (not the only solution)

1. parse the string through parseHtml method with dummy url
2. get the second table by xpath
3. iterate with double nested loop (for and iterator -to append separator correctly-)

### ExtractTableData:

```
import java.net.URL;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.StringWebResponse;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTable;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTableRow;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTableRow.CellIterator;


public class ExtractTableData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String html = "<div class=\"top_red_bar\">\n" + "                        <div id=\"site-breadcrumbs\">\n"
                + "                            <a href=\"/admin/index.jsp\" title=\"Home\">Home</a>\n"
                + "                            &#124;\n"
                + "                            <a href=\"/admin/queues.jsp\" title=\"Queues\">Queues</a>\n"
                + "                            &#124;\n"
                + "                            <a href=\"/admin/topics.jsp\" title=\"Topics\">Topics</a>\n"
                + "                            &#124;\n"
                + "                            <a href=\"/admin/subscribers.jsp\" title=\"Subscribers\">Subscribers</a>\n"
                + "                            &#124;\n"
                + "                            <a href=\"/admin/connections.jsp\" title=\"Connections\">Connections</a>\n"
                + "                            &#124;\n"
                + "                            <a href=\"/admin/network.jsp\" title=\"Network\">Network</a>\n"
                + "                            &#124;\n"
                + "                             <a href=\"/admin/scheduled.jsp\" title=\"Scheduled\">Scheduled</a>\n"
                + "                            &#124;\n" + "                            <a href=\"/admin/send.jsp\"\n"
                + "                               title=\"Send\">Send</a>\n" + "                        </div>\n"
                + "                        <div id=\"site-quicklinks\"><P>\n"
                + "                            <a href=\"http://activemq.apache.org/support.html\"\n"
                + "                               title=\"Get help and support using Apache ActiveMQ\">Support</a></p>\n"
                + "                        </div>\n" + "                    </div>\n" + "\n"
                + "                    <table border=\"0\">\n" + "                        <tbody>\n"
                + "                            <tr>\n"
                + "                                <td valign=\"top\" width=\"100%\" style=\"overflow:hidden;\">\n"
                + "                                    <div class=\"body-content\">\n" + "\n" + "\n"
                + "<h2>Welcome!</h2>\n" + "\n" + "<p>\n"
                + "Welcome to the Apache ActiveMQ Console of <b>localhost</b> (ID:TOOLCONTROLPJX526-524666-65544585445-2:3)\n"
                + "</p>\n" + "\n" + "<p>\n"
                + "You can find more information about Apache ActiveMQ on the <a href=\"http://activemq.apache.org/\">Apache ActiveMQ Site</a>\n"
                + "</p>\n" + "\n" + "<h2>Broker</h2>\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "<table>\n" + "    <tr>\n"
                + "        <td>Name</td>\n" + "        <td><b>localhost</b></td>\n" + "    </tr>\n" + "    <tr>\n"
                + "        <td>Version</td>\n" + "        <td><b>5.13.3</b></td>\n" + "    </tr>\n" + "    <tr>\n"
                + "        <td>ID</td>\n" + "        <td><b>ID:TOOLCONTROLPJX526-524666-65544585445-2:3</b></td>\n"
                + "    </tr>\n" + "    <tr>\n" + "        <td>Uptime</td>\n"
                + "        <td><b>17 days 13 hours</b></td>\n" + "    </tr>\n" + "    <tr>\n"
                + "        <td>Store percent used</td>\n" + "        <td><b>19</b></td>\n" + "    </tr>\n"
                + "    <tr>\n" + "        <td>Memory percent used</td>\n" + "        <td><b>0</b></td>\n"
                + "    </tr>\n" + "    <tr>\n" + "        <td>Temp percent used</td>\n" + "        <td><b>0</b></td>\n"
                + "    </tr>\n" + "</table>";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = HTMLParser.parseHtml(new StringWebResponse(html, new URL("http://dummy.url.for.parsing.com/")),
                webClient.getCurrentWindow());

        final HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable) page.getByXPath("//table").get(1);

        for (final HtmlTableRow row : table.getRows()) {

            CellIterator cellIterator = row.getCellIterator();

            if (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(cellIterator.next().asText());
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.print(":" + cellIterator.next().asText());
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

### Output:

```
Name:localhost
Version:5.13.3
ID:ID:TOOLCONTROLPJX526-524666-65544585445-2:3
Uptime:17 days 13 hours
Store percent used:19
Memory percent used:0
Temp percent used:0
```

Comment: @Rcordoval..Thanks for sharing ..! Really appreciate..! I'll try by myself now..!